# How to determine if an entity has been continually active across multiple database records?

Tags: sql, oracle

**Example data set where each row records the active time period of a stint of a unique person/major combination**

*Note: All records belonging to each of the following person_IDs are shown in this example data set*

*Note2: A termination date of 9999/12/31 just means the person is currently enrolled in that major.*

```
TBL_MAJORS

Person_ID   Major         Effective_Date   Termination_Date
76          Biology       2016/8/1         2017/2/24   
76          Accounting    2017/2/25        2017/4/15  
76          Math          2017/4/16        9999/12/31         
102         Physics       2016/8/1         2018/7/21
58          Literature    2016/8/1         2017/5/13
94          Art History   2016/8/1         2017/8/30   
94          Comp Sci      2018/3/1         9999/12/31
```

**End goal data set with a new column indicating whether each person was continuously enrolled in a major throughout the year of 2017**

```
TBL_MAJORS_2

Person_ID   Major         Effective_Date   Termination_Date   Active_Throughout_2017
76          Biology       2016/8/1         2017/2/24          1
76          Accounting    2017/2/25        2017/4/15          1
76          Math          2017/4/16        9999/12/31         1
102         Physics       2016/8/1         2018/7/21          1
58          Literature    2016/8/1         2017/5/13          0
94          Art History   2016/8/1         2017/8/30          0
94          Comp Sci      2018/3/1         9999/12/31         0
```

**A bit more explanation**

So, for example, person 76 had three different majors spanning continuously from 2016/8/1 to 9999/12/31 (i.e they're currently enrolled), so they were continuously enrolled throughout 2017.

On the other hand, person 94 had two different majors, but there was a gap in activity from 2017/8/31 to 2018/2/28, so they weren't continuously enrolled throughout 2017.

Can anyone help me achieve this? Bonus kudos if you can make it perform well... I'm thinking that maybe this would involve some sort of window/analytic function, but I'm honestly stumped.

Comment: Well, I can give you a hint - for each record calculate how many days person was enrolled within 2017 year. Then sum it up join to your original table and check if the total sum of days enrolled in 2017 is equal to the number of total days in 2017.

Comment: Oh, that's so elegant and should work well with my actual data set. Thank you for this helpful idea.

Comment: Maybe your answer is in here: https://stewashton.wordpress.com/2014/03/15/gaps-in-date-ranges-when-are-you-free/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done like so:

```
WITH tbl_majors AS (SELECT 76 person_id, 'Biology' major, to_date('01/08/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') effective_date, to_date('24/02/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') termination_date FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 76 person_id, 'Accounting' major, to_date('25/02/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') effective_date, to_date('15/04/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') termination_date FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 76 person_id, 'Math' major, to_date('16/04/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') effective_date, to_date('31/12/9999', 'dd/mm/yyyy') termination_date FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 102 person_id, 'Physics' major, to_date('01/08/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') effective_date, to_date('21/07/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') termination_date FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 58 person_id, 'Literature' major, to_date('01/08/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') effective_date, to_date('13/05/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') termination_date FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 94 person_id, 'Art History' major, to_date('01/08/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') effective_date, to_date('30/08/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') termination_date FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 94 person_id, 'Comp Sci' major, to_date('01/03/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') effective_date, to_date('31/12/9999', 'dd/mm/yyyy') termination_date FROM dual)
SELECT person_id,
       major,
       effective_date,
       termination_date,
       CASE WHEN to_date('01/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') >= MIN(effective_date) OVER (PARTITION BY person_id, grp)
                 AND to_date('31/12/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') <= MAX(termination_date) OVER (PARTITION BY person_id, grp)
                 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
       END active_throughout_2017
FROM   (SELECT person_id,
               major,
               effective_date,
               termination_date,
               SUM(new_grp_start) OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY effective_date) grp
        FROM   (SELECT person_id,
                       major,
                       effective_date,
                       termination_date,
                       CASE WHEN effective_date = LAG(termination_date) OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY effective_date) + 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END new_grp_start
                FROM   tbl_majors));

 PERSON_ID MAJOR       EFFECTIVE_DATE TERMINATION_DATE ACTIVE_THROUGHOUT_2017
---------- ----------- -------------- ---------------- ----------------------
        58 Literature  01/08/2016     13/05/2017                            0
        76 Accounting  25/02/2017     15/04/2017                            1
        76 Biology     01/08/2016     24/02/2017                            1
        76 Math        16/04/2017     31/12/9999                            1
        94 Art History 01/08/2016     30/08/2017                            0
        94 Comp Sci    01/03/2018     31/12/9999                            0
       102 Physics     01/08/2016     21/07/2018                            1
```

This works by first working out if the current row and previous row are consecutive or not - i.e. whether the current row's effective_date is 1 greater than that of the previous row's termination_date.

Once we know if the previous row was consecutive or not, we know that's the start of a new group. We can then do a cumulative sum on this, meaning that all consecutive rows will get the same number, and the number increases each time a new group of rows is started.

Then it's a simple matter of working out the min effective_date and max termination_date for each person and group, and then doing an overlaps comparison with the first and last days in 2017.

---

ETA: Here's a solution based on GSazheniuk's suggestion:

```
WITH tbl_majors AS (SELECT 76 person_id, 'Biology' major, to_date('01/08/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') effective_date, to_date('24/02/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') termination_date FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 76 person_id, 'Accounting' major, to_date('25/02/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') effective_date, to_date('15/04/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') termination_date FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 76 person_id, 'Math' major, to_date('16/04/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') effective_date, to_date('31/12/9999', 'dd/mm/yyyy') termination_date FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 102 person_id, 'Physics' major, to_date('01/08/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') effective_date, to_date('21/07/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') termination_date FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 58 person_id, 'Literature' major, to_date('01/08/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') effective_date, to_date('13/05/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') termination_date FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 94 person_id, 'Art History' major, to_date('01/08/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') effective_date, to_date('30/08/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') termination_date FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 94 person_id, 'Comp Sci' major, to_date('01/03/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') effective_date, to_date('31/12/9999', 'dd/mm/yyyy') termination_date FROM dual)
SELECT person_id,
       major,
       effective_date,
       termination_date,
       CASE WHEN SUM(LEAST(to_date('31/12/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), termination_date) + 1 - GREATEST(to_date('01/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), effective_date)) OVER (PARTITION BY person_id)
                   = to_date('31/12/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') + 1 - to_date('01/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
                 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
       END active_throughout_2017
FROM   tbl_majors;
```

As you can see, it's a lot more elegant than my original solution. You should test both to see which one is more performant for your data, etc.

Both solutions assume that there won't be an overlap (i.e. a student will only ever have one major at any one moment in time); you'd have to adjust them accordingly to cater for cases when someone might have more than one major at a time.

Comment: Thank you so much. You're my hero for the day.

Comment: I would say that GSazheniuk’s idea of summing the 2017 days is much more elegant, simpler and most likely more performant than my answer, though!